# Google Cloud Function does not terminate on res.send() but continues to execute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have coded some GCF on Firebase. Project structure: I got index.js which declares all functions. Each function is in individual .js files. I have some util functions e.g. sendSuccess or sendFailure where in I have coded

```
function _respondSuccess(res, status, data, httpCode) {
 var response = {
   'status': status,
   'successFlag' : true,
   'data' : data
 };
 res.status(httpCode).send(response);
}

function _respondFailure(res, status, data, httpCode) {
 var response = {
   'status': status,
   'successFlag' : false,
   'data' : data
 };
 res.status(httpCode).send(response);
}
```

I call this function from individual GCF function on success or failure. But in case of failure e.g. a condition -if- one of the params is null and I call _respondFailure internal function the code in GCF still continues with next code statements. I get GCF error in console logs - Unhandled Rejection - Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
    at _respondFailure (/user_code/banks/getBanks.js:77:10)
    at failure (/user_code/banks/getBanks.js:103:2)
    at /user_code/banks/getBanks.js:228:18
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Any help to get it rectified? or I have to go back to Firebase team for support?

Thanks

```
9:29:57.712 AM
```

warning 
getBanksFunction
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11) at ServerResponse.header (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10) at _respondFailure (/user_code/banks/getBanks.js:77:10) at failure (/user_code/banks/getBanks.js:103:2) at /user_code/banks/getBanks.js:228:18 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
9:29:57.711 AM
warning 
getBanksFunction
Unhandled rejection
9:29:55.110 AM
info
getBanksFunction
response value - undefined
9:29:55.110 AM
info
getBanksFunction
error value -true
9:29:46.014 AM
info
getBanksFunction
Checking if index Exists(banks_index_v1)
9:29:45.923 AM
outlined_flag
getBanksFunction
Function execution took 14 ms, finished with status code: 401
9:29:45.923 AM
info
getBanksFunction
sizeVal = 10 , page =undefined , fromVal = 0
9:29:45.921 AM
info
getBanksFunction
Error: 401 Error: req.query.routingUid required to create Index in ES ->undefined
9:29:45.921 AM
info
getBanksFunction
req.query.size = undefined
9:29:45.921 AM
info
getBanksFunction
req.query.page = undefined
9:29:45.921 AM
info
getBanksFunction
req.query.uid = undefined

Function invoked in index.js

```
exports.getBanksFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res, () => {
    getBanksFunction.handler(req, res, database, esClient);
});
});
```

Call from GCF function logic

```
console.log('Inside serer.post(getbanks)');
console.log('req.query.uid = ' + req.query.uid);
console.log('req.query.page = ' + req.query.page);
console.log('req.query.size = ' + req.query.size);
var routingUid = req.query.uid;
var page = req.query.page;
var sizeVal = req.query.size;
var fromVal = 0;

 if(routingUid === null || routingUid === undefined) {
     resMsg = "Error: req.query.routingUid required to create Index in ES ->" + routingUid;
    helper.failure(res,resMsg,401);
  }
 if(sizeVal == null || sizeVal === undefined)
   sizeVal = 10;
 if(page === null || page === undefined)
   fromVal = 0;
 else
   fromVal  = page * Number(sizeVal);

 console.log('sizeVal = '+sizeVal+' , page ='+page+" , fromVal = "+fromVal);
```

Comment: GCF logs for benefit:

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimum **complete** code that reproduces the issue. Right now we're missing how this code is invoked from within Cloud Functions, which is likely quite crucial to the problem you're having.

Comment: Hi, The code is invoked using HTTPS exports.getBanksFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        getBanksFunction.handler(req, res, database, esClient);
    });
});   in index.js

Comment: var resMsg = '';
   console.log('Inside serer.post(getbanks)');
   console.log('req.query.uid = ' + req.query.uid);
   console.log('req.query.page = ' + req.query.page);
   console.log('req.query.size = ' + req.query.size);
   var routingUid = req.query.uid;
   var page = req.query.page;
   var sizeVal = req.query.size;
   var fromVal = 0;

   if(routingUid === null || routingUid === undefined) {
    resMsg = "Error: req.query.routingUid required to create Index in ES ->" + routingUid;
    helper.failure(res,resMsg,401);
   }

Comment: if(sizeVal == null || sizeVal === undefined)
      sizeVal = 10;
   if(page === null || page === undefined)
      fromVal = 0;
   else
      fromVal  = page * Number(sizeVal);

Comment: function success (res, data) {
 _respondSuccess(res, 'success', data, 200);
}

function failure (res, data, httpCode) {
 console.log('Error: ' + httpCode + ' ' + data);
 _respondFailure(res, 'failure', data, httpCode);
}

Comment: I hope it will help the case now.

Comment: Please use the edit link under your question to put the additional information inside your question. That also allows you to format it.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have now edited the code in mail question.

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going wrong here. Largely that may be due to the fact that your code is over multiple snippets that are hard to relate. Maybe someone else spots the problem. But otherwise please read on [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which contains helpful information on making it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank Frank. Let me go through the documentation link you suggested. and repost the query.

Comment: Hi, I resolved it using Promise. I think it is a dirty way to serialise async architecture.